# Merging price time series in xts when securities show no data

Tags: r, merge, xts, bloomberg

I am querying a security DB. Price series are in xts and for some there might be no data (for the chosen window). Actual time series can be simulated as follows:

```
require(xts)

## Simulated time series
price=function(){
    x=floor(runif(1,1,4))
    xts(round(rnorm(x,5),3), Sys.Date()+1:x)    
}
## Sample tickers
(tick1=setNames(price(), "tick1"))
#            tick1
# 2014-04-20 5.829
# 2014-04-21 6.061
# 2014-04-22 5.813
(tick2=setNames(price(), "tick2"))
#            tick2
# 2014-04-20 6.458
# 2014-04-21 5.373
(tick3=xts(data.frame(tick3=numeric()), as.Date(numeric()))) # Security showing no data
#            tick3
## ...
## tickn
```

No need to mention that I don't know in advance which security will show no data.

If I merge the prices in a single xts object, `merge.xts` completely removes from the output the empty security(ies):

```
(port=merge(tick1, tick2, tick3))
#            tick1 tick2
# 2014-04-20 5.829 6.458
# 2014-04-21 6.061 5.373
# 2014-04-22 5.813    NA
```

Instead I would like to keep trace of them, therefore printing an output similar to:

```
(cbind(port, tick3=NA))
#            tick1 tick2 tick3
# 2014-04-20 5.829 6.458    NA
# 2014-04-21 6.061 5.373    NA
# 2014-04-22 5.813    NA    NA
```

One possible solution is:

```
port=list(tick1, tick2, tick3) # ... tickn
port.m=lapply(port, function(sec){
    if(nrow(sec)==0) sec= xts(matrix(NA, dimnames=dimnames(tick3)), Sys.Date())
    sec
})
(port.m=do.call('merge', port.m))
#            tick1 tick2 tick3
# 2014-04-19    NA    NA    NA
# 2014-04-20 5.829 6.458    NA
# 2014-04-21 6.061 5.373    NA
# 2014-04-22 5.813    NA    NA
if(all(is.na(port.m[Sys.Date()])))
    (port.m=port.m[time(port.m)!=Sys.Date()])
#            tick1 tick2 tick3
# 2014-04-20 5.829 6.458    NA
# 2014-04-21 6.061 5.373    NA
# 2014-04-22 5.813    NA    NA
```

*Is it possible to find a smarter solution?*

Comment: `merge.xts` does not "remove the empty securities". `tick3` is not just missing data; it has a zero-length index, so there's nothing to merge. "I'm missing data for some dates" is different from "I don't have any dates". This is also consistent with `merge.zoo`. Why not simply: `if(nrow(sec)==0) sec=NA`?

Answer (score 1):

You are making two mistakes here:
First: You need to use a vector of non-zero length. See this:

```
length(integer())
length(NA)
```

Second: For merge to work, the xts object indices have to match some where.

e.g. something like this will work:

```
require(xts)
x=xts(1:4, Sys.Date()+1:4)
v=xts(NA, Sys.Date()+1) 
(m=merge.xts(x,v))
```

Here the starting index matches, and remaining indices are filled up.

If you want to be very particular, you could probably try something like this:

```
v=xts(rep(NA,4), Sys.Date()+1:4)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: +1, but a small correction: the indices _do not_ have to overlap. For example: `merge(x=.xts(1,1),y=.xts(1,2))`.

Comment: Your answer is off topic. As I wrote, I need to work with these data. I can't ask the provider (an exchange) to make it such to fit my needs. If there were `NA`'s in the void xts objects, I wouldn't have posted here. BTW, for "marketing" reasons I restated the question in financial terms (to attract a wider audience) and I also provide a boring, but *working* solution.

Comment: Dude... you have totally edited the original question... I was answering your original question. Not the one that you have now!! Anyways... Best wishes!